# Difficulty in reading a series of whitespace separated DNA string into different locations of an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, dna-sequence

I am trying to read in a string of whitespace separated strings from a file that goes like:

```
CGGCGGGAGATT CGGGAGATTCAA CGTGCGGCGGGA CGTGGAGGCGTG CGTGGCGTGCGG GCGTGCGGCGGG GCGTGGAGGCGT GCGTGGCGTGCG GGAGAAGCGAGA GGAGATTCAAGC GGCGGGAGATTC GGGAGATTCAAG GTGCGGCGGGAG TGCGGCGGGAGA
```

My code to achieve this is

```
char id_dna_seqs[14][12];
fscanf(dataset, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", id_dna_seqs[0], id_dna_seqs[1], id_dna_seqs[2], id_dna_seqs[3], id_dna_seqs[4], id_dna_seqs[5], id_dna_seqs[6], id_dna_seqs[7], id_dna_seqs[8], id_dna_seqs[9], id_dna_seqs[10], id_dna_seqs[11], id_dna_seqs[12], id_dna_seqs[13]);
```

but when I do a test printout of the array, I don't get what I expect to get. For example, doing

```
printf("%s\n", id_dna_seqs[4]);
```

gives

```
CGTGGCGTGCGGGCGTGCGGCGGGGCGTGGAGGCGTGCGTGGCGTGCGGGAGAAGCGAGAGGAGATTCAAGCGGCGGGAGATTCGGGAGATTCAAGGTGCGGCGGGAGTGCGGCGGGAGA
```

which upon closer examination, I realized is actually printing all of the strings starting from the 5th element in the char* array. What I want to achieve is to be able to individually index each string correctly for example, with reference to the strings in the file, the 5th string is the sequence `CGTGGCGTGCGG`, so I want printing `id_dna_seqs[4]` to give me just that instead of everything starting from the 5th string element.

Please let me know what is wrong here, and I look forward to your suggestions for improvement. Thank you!

Comment: C-"string"s need to provide one ***more*** char to store the `0`-terminator. 14 chunks with 12 characters each need: `char id_dna_seqs[14][13];` This assumes a non-multi-byte character text file.

Comment: Why [12]?   Surely, you didn't count up?  If you count up, you will make mistakes, eg. forgetting to allow space for null terminators...  Just look at the input and say 'OK, 32 would be fine for that dimension'.

Comment: @alk Over, and over, and over again with the bean-counters:((

Comment: There is nothing wrong with bean-counting in the 1st place, even more with refusing to RTFM. @MartinJames

Comment: @alk : I've definitely learnt about the null terminated string thing in C before, and that the printf() function is designed to recognize the null termination before to stop printing. But I didn't realize that I would need to ensure my array is one more character larger to account for that! That puzzles me now because then why is it that the null character got stored in the end of id_dna_seqs[13], even though that last string was also only allocated 12 characters only? (which is probably the case since printf() knew that it had to stop at the last string)?

Comment: Alternative to "`n+1` allocating and `\0` terminating" would another kind of "bean-counting": `for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)printf("%c", id_dna_seqs[4][i]);` or whatever you may feel like abstracting and wrapping it into. In that case you don't deal with strings anymore (-:

Comment: @alk there is a lot wrong with it . Every day, there are SO posts with obi-wan errors because the posters spend time on laboriously counting chars to precisely size their buffers..and get it wrong.  Those who shove in [128] without thinking too hard about it don't post SO questions:)

Comment: @martinjames: And those guys placing those angst -bytes then  end up with voodoo-code. :-(

Comment: @user3078414: Cortect, but  'scanf' then would invoke undefined behaviour by placeing the NUL out -of -bounds.

Comment: @akka: That the printf found a 0 at the expected place was pure "bad" luck,  hiding the malfunction.

Comment: @alk : That clarifies then! So technically it shouldn't have been null terminated as I did not correctly specify my array size to include that location of memory, but somehow I got "lucky" that it was a 0 lol. Also if its possible for you to explain here, do you have any suggestions on a better way that I could have read in the DNA strings? I kind of feel that what I've implemented here is not really the best way possible...